# Remove line breaks in a xml file, in tags and between, keeping the structure

Tags: php, regex, xml, tags, preg-replace

Long title :)

Anyways, I have many XML files that I wish to clean up on fly, simple convert on fly with PHP preg_replace RegEx output.

Now I can't make the changes permanent, so I've written a php function to go thru the file.

What I can't fix is the RegEx pattern.

https://regex101.com/r/bN5eF4/7

I want to match:

```
<all-tags with-their="attribute"
even-if-there="are-more">
and all the content between the start and end tag
even if there
are line breaks
in between them
</all-tags>
```

I bet it's very simple, but I've never handled RegEx very well... sadly.

**Edited**

Seems people want me to build a parser function of SimpleXML, that goes throu the xml file and remove the line breaks?

In the same process, I want to remove some elements with their content, depending on what it says in their attributes. ***Profiling*** so to speak.

I thought doing line breaks and profiling before processing the xml file with Xsltprocessor would be the faster choice?

Comment: Don't parse XML with regex; use a real XML parser.

Comment: For this purpose, RegEx is much faster, since I'm loading it as a string and then just want to remove line break within tags and between tags.

Comment: Detecting when you're within and between tags is not a job for regex.

Comment: Come with a better suggestion then?

Comment: Already did: Use a real XML parser.

Comment: Dude, give examples instead of being wage...

With that, I mean, show how you would have done it.

I've tried doing it with a parser, but the method I came to use, was more time consuming and less effiant than something simple as removing the all line breaks in the xml file with preg_replace and then tell all start and end tags to have a line break after them.

Comment: See [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).  If your attempts failed, show a [mcve] and you'll get tons of help.

Comment: You've overextended your questioning.  Please read the links I provided along with [ask].  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it with 2 regex patterns.
**Input:**

```
<all-tags 
   with-their="attribute"

   even-if-there="are-more"
aa="1">
and all the content between
 the start and end tag
</all-tags>
<meta-tag />
```

1. remove newline before open tag and after closing tag https://regex101.com/r/PPzkWv/2/

```
/(?<=\>)(\n+)|(\n+)(?=\<)/
```

Output:

```
<all-tags 
   with-their="attribute"

   even-if-there="are-more"
aa="1">and all the content between
 the start and end tag</all-tags><meta-tag />
```

2. from the output remove newlines inside tags without breaking semantic https://regex101.com/r/GvBc7J/3/

```
/(\s?\n+\s+|\n)/
```

**Final output**:

```
<all-tags with-their="attribute" even-if-there="are-more" aa="1">and all the content between the start and end tag</all-tags><meta-tag />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex:

```
/(?<=\>)(\r?\n)|(\r?\n)(?=\<\/)/
```

Here you are searching for newline character at end of `>` or at beginning of `</` and replacing it will empty string.

See demo at [Regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/bN7qN8/1)

Based on your sample input text, it will remove all newlines and emit content as:

```
<all-tags with-their="attribute" even-if-there="are-more">and all the content between the start and end tag</all-tags>
```